# How to run JavaFX application from Notepad++? (Only runs as .jar file)

Tags: java, javafx, notepad++, nppexec

How do you correctly run a JavaFX Application from <strike>cmd</strike> **Notepad++'s plug-in, NppExec**? I previously used the command `java $(NAME_PART)` on the Notepad++ plugin NppExec (which is *basically* a built-in cmd) to run java which worked fine for swing-based programs. However, when I use that command to run a JavaFX Application, my Notepad++ window seems to lose focus as if a new window was opened but nothing appears.

EDIT: I discovered the problem lies in the Notepad++ plugin NppExec after testing the same command from the cmd. NppExec doesn't seem to function the same as the cmd when running JavaFX Applications.

The code I am using to test (which was originally obtained from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html) will be updated according to the edits above:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MyApp extends Application {
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Circle circ = new Circle(40, 40, 30);
        Group root = new Group(circ);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 300);

        stage.setTitle("My JavaFX Application");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    //not required but recommended
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your main method ?

Comment: I am new to JavaFX so excuse me if I'm incorrect but I believe JavaFX Applications do not require a main method.

Comment: @ATH that is correct, JavaFX apps don't need a main.  Some IDEs or tools may expect a main though to allow the app to be executed from within the IDE environment.  Also, sometimes the lack of a main confuses developers who expect to see a main, so it's probably best to always include a main to your app, even if all it does is just invoke the launch method.

Comment: Ahh.. I never tried that ! This is the first time I tried it out and it works without the main as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question.

From NppExec's manual,

`- NppExec is not a command interpreter. NppExec does not understand such commands as 'copy', 'call', 'for' and so on because it is neither a "real" console nor a console emulator. However, NppExec has its own internal implementation of such commands as 'cls', 'cd', 'dir', 'echo', 'set' ('env_set') and introduces other, specific, commands. Also you can use "cmd /c <command>" to execute any cmd's command inside NppExec.`

Using `cmd /c java $(NAME_PART)` rather than `java $(NAME_PART)` to run successfully worked.

Still unsure why simply calling `java $(NAME_PART)` works for non-JavaFX programs but fails for JavaFX programs but I don't think the issue belongs here.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work:

```
npp_save
cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\javac "$(FILE_NAME)"
cmd /c cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" && java "$(NAME_PART)"
```

The key was to be able to run two commands on one line. The `&&` expression does this. 
In case you were wondering, the second command will not run if the first command is not executed successfully.

Make sure you have Java in your environment variables on your computer. If you don't then you will have to supply the full path to the Java executable.

```
npp_save
cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\javac "$(FILE_NAME)"
cmd /c cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" && "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\java.exe" "$(NAME_PART)"
```